# How do I downgrade gcc-core to 4.8.1-3 successfully?

Tags: c++, gcc

I've been having an issue with setting up my compiler for use in netbeans. The errors that I'm getting are the following:

When I run compile via the netbeans 'play' button.

> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 467ms)

When I compile it through the terminal.

> fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory  #include
>
> compilation terminated.

I've read through alot, tried half a dozen fixes which didn't quite fix it but I think I'm closing in on a solution thanks to the quoted text below which was also on this forum.

> I noticed that there are two folders of gcc here
>   C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.8.1
>   C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.8.2
>
> and g++ --version gives 4.8.2
>
> Running Cygwin's latest Setup.exe and looking for installed packets
>   showed that versions mismatch for gcc-core and gcc-g++ :
>
> gcc-core = 4.8.2-1
>
> gcc-c++ = 4.8.1-3
>
> I downgraded gcc-core to 4.8.1-3 and fixed the issue.

Now I managed to deduct that I'm also having two different folders of gcc and basicly my current state is the exact same as is described. However my question now would be, which of the following files is the one that I need to attempt a fix and in what directory is this file supposed to be located, because I cant quite find it.

> gcc-core-4.8.1-3-mingw32-man.tar.lzma 2013-09-24
>
> gcc-core-4.8.1-3-mingw32-info.tar.lzma    2013-09-24
>
> gcc-core-4.8.1-3-mingw32-lic.tar.lzma 2013-09-24
>
> gcc-core-4.8.1-3-mingw32-doc.tar.lzma 2013-09-24
>
> gcc-core-4.8.1-3-mingw32-dll.tar.lzma 2013-09-24
>
> gcc-core-4.8.1-3-mingw32-dev.tar.lzma 2013-09-24
>
> gcc-core-4.8.1-3-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma 2013-09-24

Comment: Should this perhaps be posted to superuser?